# MVC3 database access using existing Postgres database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, postgresql, razor, npgsql

I have an application based on 3 tier architecture with postgres database(npgsql) having more than 400 stored procedures, And now i want to develop the same application using MVC3 Framework.

I would like to know whats the best possible way to use the existing database with those stored procedures, I have come across code first approach (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx) but would like to know if its the best solution.

Also i read about benefits of Razor however my application has lots of DataGridViews and TabContorls so i was wondering would it be easy to go with Razor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to decide what level of refactor or the transformation level you need to go with developing your existing application using MVC3, because you probably will throw most of your work

Because of the following:

Working with MVC as technology is related some how  with DDD as OOP design or normal OOP,  and in both approaches the main layer is the Domain Model not the DB, so you will need to translate all your stored procedures to business logic inside the Domain Model itself or otherwise use the existing DB and in this case you will lose one of the big benefit of using MVC

Working with MVC in the presentation layer not consider working with DataGridViews or TabContorls, so you will need to throw them too, and there is no solution to re-use them.

At the end, the main benefits of using MVC,,are the capability of unit testing and the high level of maintainability that MVC provide, because the nature of the pattern and the approach itself>

So you have to really think very good of what level of transomation you want to achieve to decide what you will keep and what you will throwaway, but my advise to you if you really will not restructure your whole project don't transform to MVC, just keep the project as it's and just refactor it and enhance the existing approach

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, I really think staying with 3 tier architecture would be smart, currently we are not facing any maintainability issues our only concern is performance.

Comment: MVC can help you to enhance the performance very well, this because it gives you more control over the presentation layer, no more generated JavaScript, no more heavy viewstate, etc. but also will required learning time to get familiar and productive with, You can also put a long term plan to migrate, finally don't miss understand me and remember I said one of the main benefit is maintainability not all the befits is maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like you have already (http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/), and then you can leverage your existing framework/infrastructure (how you query your database from your existing application).

Secondly, If you are using DataGridViews and TabControls, ASP.NET MVC doesn't really work with server controls, you will either have to get an HtmlHelper that gives you a grid, or build one yourself.

The question I think that needs to be asked is, why do you want to go MVC vs WebForms 4.0?

Comment: Our concern is Performance and that's the reason we are trying to move to MVC. Will MVC provide any help in performance ?